# how to model subdocument (MONGODB) in sails.js

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

### Hello

any of you know how to model this document from MONGODB in sails.js?

#### this is a example, of the document on mongodb

```
{   
    "Iden_Codigo" : "13444",
    "Iden_Aseguradora" : NumberLong(25),
    "AdaptacionCanguro" : {
        "AC_LugarAC" : NumberLong(2)
    },
    "CaracteristicasSocioProfesionales" : {
        "CSP_SituaPareja" : NumberLong(3)
    }
}
```

#### This is my solution but it is not right, someone can help me please

```
module.exports = {
tableName: 'Pacientes',
    attributes: {
        Iden_Codigo: {type: 'string',required: true},
        Iden_Aseguradora: { type: 'integer' },
        CaracteristicasSocioProfesionales: {
            CSP_SituaPareja: { type: 'integer' }
        },
        AdaptacionCanguro : {
            AC_LugarAC : { type: 'integer' }
        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't need this once. When I've to save a reference or sub document I just pass it as a whole JSON and Sails.js/Waterline handles it correctly. E. G. when I save the ID it gets automatically converted to a referenced object ID in MongoDB.